# IE8 developer tools debugger gives wrong exception information

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, exception, error-handling

Check out this jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/yxJey/6/

When run in FF with firebug you get the correct exception information.

When run in IE8 with developer tools the exception information is meaningless - only jQuery internals are shown, but not the exact line that caused the error. This makes things very hard to debug with IE. Any ideas why this happens and how to work around?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer? The debugger of Internet Explorer is not a very high-quality piece of software.

The long answer:

Debuggers find out about problems only when they are actively looking for them. Some debuggers, are strict, and will show errors anytime they see something that might induce problems later on.

However, there are many debuggers that will only show errors when they really bump with their head against a wall and realize they have lost all sense of what is supposed to happen.

Workarounds might be:

1. Try not to make any mistakes.(I know this is impossible, but theoretically it is the best option ;D)
2. Try to fix errors that are not IE-specific in another debugger such as FireFox with Firebug